# Problem using function with react-responsive-carousel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-responsive-carousel

I'm using react-responsive-carousel and trying to make that when I click on the slide image it opens a modal according to the code described below

The problem is that for each image I want it to open a different modal and the `onClickItem` field only accepts one function

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css";
import { Carousel } from 'react-responsive-carousel';
import styles from '../../styles/slider.module.css'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'


const Modal = dynamic(() => import('../Modal'), { ssr: false });

function Corrosel() {


 // const [secIsModalVisible1, setSecIsModalVisible1] = useState(false);
 const [secIsModalVisible2, setSecIsModalVisible2] = useState(false);
 const [secIsModalVisible3, setSecIsModalVisible3] = useState(false);

        return (
            <div className='text-center'>
              <Carousel 
              infiniteLoop={true}
              autoPlay={true}
              showIndicators={true}
              showThumbs={false}
              width='100%'
              transitionTime={2000}
              showArrows={true}
              swipeable={true}
              emulateTouch={true}
              centerMode={true}
              onClickItem={onChange}
              onClickThumb={true}
              centerSlidePercentage={85}
              axis="horizontal"
              className={styles.slider}>

                  <div className={styles.sliderimage}>
                      <img onClick={() => setSecIsModalVisible2(true)} 
                      src="/images/imagem_youtube.png" alt="image2" />
                      
                  </div>
                  <div className={styles.sliderimage}>
                      <img onClick={() => setSecIsModalVisible3(true)}
                      src="/images/imagem_youtube.png" alt="image3"/>
                      <p className="legend">Image 3</p>
  
                  </div>

              </Carousel>
              <div>
              <div>
          {secIsModalVisible2 ? (
          <Modal onClose={() => setSecIsModalVisible2(false)}>
          <div className={styles.tamanhovideotiktok}>
              <iframe
                src="https://www.tiktok.com/embed/7072819797184171310"
                className={styles.tamanhovideodentrotiktok}
                allowFullScreen="true"
                scrolling="no"
                allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share" 
              ></iframe>
            <h4 className='px-0.5 py-0.5 ml-1 font-bold'>Veja o vídeo no facebook <a className='text-blue-600' href="https://web.facebook.com/watch/?v=678531976681251">aqui</a> </h4>
          </div>
          </Modal> 
          )  : null}
        </div>
        <div>
          {secIsModalVisible3 ? (
          <Modal onClose={() => setSecIsModalVisible3(false)}>
          <div className={styles.tamanhovideotiktok}>
          <iframe  className={styles.tamanhovideodentrofacebook} containerClassName={"youtubeContainer"}
            src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?height=314&href=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.facebook.com%2Fneymarjr%2Fvideos%2F546587226603922%2F&show_text=true&width=560&t=0" 
            scrolling="no" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>    
            <h4 className='px-0.5 py-0.5 ml-1 font-bold'> Veja o vídeo no facebook <a className='text-blue-600' href="https://web.facebook.com/watch/?v=678531976681251">aqui</a> </h4>
          </div>
          </Modal> 
          )  : null}
        </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        );
    }


export default Corrosel
```

Comment: I think you've painted yourself into a bit of a corner here. Look how much markup those modals share. You don't want one function per modal, but rather one generic function or component that accepts props or params for those values that are different from modal to modal. Hope this helps.

Comment: I understand but I don't know how to do it. I'm new to this.

Comment: @HenrikErstad Can you do how to start a code as you proposed?